# Apply Background Image to Listactivty in android

Tags: android, colors, background-image, listactivity, android-theme

This is my android activity which uses a listactivity. I need to give a background image which is located at the res->drawable-hdpi folder. This is Bid_History.java page. In the corresponding activity xml page I have not given any list view. The program works fine without any problem. But I need to set a background to this listactivity .The background image to be used is located in the res->drawable-hdpi folder. I have tried many ways, but still it won't work at all. Can someone please help me in setting a background image for this activity.

```
package com.example.onlineauction;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Bid_History extends ListActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_bid__history);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Bid_History.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arraydetails));
        //arraydetails is an arraylist which contains the data to be displayed in the listactivity.
         //Data part here. 
}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

   // Data part here
        }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bid__history, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

This is my xml page.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Bid_History" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This:

```
getListView().setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the background image in the code as  `getListView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bckimage);`

Also add `getListView().setCacheColorHint(android.R.color.transparent);`

Answer (score 0):

You can define a layout for your list activity. Make sure it has a ListView with id android:list.
Add a background drawable to the layout.
Use this layout in OnCreate (setContentView) method.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:alpha="0.6"
    android:background="@drawable/background_img" >
    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```